# Find duplicate in list and draw square - turtle/python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to develop this 'Connect Four' game for school. However, I'm having some trouble trying to draw above the square that are already full.

```
def play_game(game):
for data in game:
    if data[0] == "a":        
        draw_square(-350, game)
    elif data[0] == "b":
        draw_square(-250, game)
    elif data[0] == "c":
        draw_square(-150, game)
    elif data[0] == "d":
        draw_square(-50, game)
    elif data[0] == "e":
        draw_square(50, game)
    elif data[0] == "f":
        draw_square(150, game)
    elif data[0] == "g":
        draw_square(250, game)
```

This is what happens when the squares are drawn. The arguments are the x value, and ive set a default y of -200. I need to increment it when there are dupes of the same string value found.
They look like this:

```
[['g', 3], ['f', 3], ['e', 4], ['a', 4]
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:
Set the y value here in the draw_square function.

```
def draw_square(x, game, y=-200):
goto(x, y)
pendown()
begin_fill()
forward(100)  # forward takes a number which is the distance to move
right(90)  # turn right
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(100)
right(90)
penup()
```

Comment: can you post the full code where you have set the y value.

Comment: I added it @RajuKomati

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  "I'm having some trouble" and "any help" are not problem specifications.  You seem to be looking for some sort of tutorial support; Stack Overflow is not a resource for that.

Comment: @JamesLergessner can you tell me how much do you want to increment the y value?  and `['g', 3]` means `g` 3 times is it right.

Comment: the 3 is the colour of the tile on the connect 4. I need to count the numbers in the list and increment every time there is a duplicate by 100. @RajuKomati

Answer (score 0):

you can use `set` to keep track of the numbers already seen. And you can also use dictionary to reduce the code in your `play_game` function.

```
def play_game(game):
    visited = set()
    y = -200
    val = {'a': -350, 'b': -250, 'c': -150, 'd': -50, 'e': 50, 'f': 150, 'g': 250}
    for data in game:
        if data[0] in val:
            if data[1] in visited:
                y += 100
                draw_square(val[data[0]], game, y)
            else:
                draw_square(val[data[0]], game)
                visited.add(data[1])
```